# mysqli bind_result and fetch

Tags: php, mysqli

I've created an arbitrary login system for users on the app I'm developing, and I am using mysqli to switch from MySQL. However, I'm having teething issues, as it will log you in successfully regardless of what data you enter. Obviously this is wrong, and I think it's got something to do with my fetch statements. Here is the code:

```
$sid = /* arbitrary value */
$con = new mysqli($mysql_host,$mysql_user,$mysql_password,$mysql_database);

$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT uid, pwd FROM schools WHERE uid=?");

$stmt->bind_param("i", $sid);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($schoolid, $password);
$stmt->fetch();

$stmt->close();
```

Anybody know what's going on here and able to describe it in plain English to a relative coding newbie?

EDIT: the rest of the code is like this for the checking system. The entered user ID is `$sid` and the entered and encrypted password is `$cleanpwd`.

```
if ($sid == $schoolid and $cleanpwd == $password) {
    header('Location: loginsuccess.php');
    }

else {
    header('Location: login.php?error=1'); }
```

Comment: Have you got a form? which sends in the data for password/username? if so, reference $_POST['Password'] with $password, if matching then login, else redirect back to the homepage

Comment: @Madbreaks What do you mean by `i`? Explain what line? because I do not see `i`?

Comment: @Madbreaks it's a type identifier

Comment: @Madbreaks: The 'i' specifies that the variable $sid is an integer.

Comment: Thanks all.  Been a while.

Comment: Just posted the additional code.

Comment: @CuriousCabbage How is `$cleanpwd` assigned?

Comment: The inputted value is $pwd, which is then encrypted, and assigned the variable $cleanpwd.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that if this is a login form are you getting the data first and then processing if it is correct? Or are you trying to process if it is correct (a userid and password combo in the SQL)? Because from this you are just putting in a userid and getting back a userid and password without checking if any entered password matches the database password associated with that userid.

If you want to see if the password and username match in the SQL you should try this:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT uid, pwd FROM schools WHERE uid=? AND pass=?");
$stmt->bind_param("is", $sid,$form_password);
$stmt->execute();
```

otherwise you need to check if the data matches up later on.

```
if($_POST['form_pass'] == $password){
//log the user in
}
```